# Change background-image when image clicked

Tags: jquery

I'll try to make this as specific as possible.  I have a set of 9 portfolio icons on my web site.  When clicking one -- I would like the "background-image" of a div to change above them.  I would preferably like it to fade-in.

This is the code for the portfolio icons:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-1.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-2.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-3.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-4.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-5.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-6.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-7.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-8.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="thumb"><span><img src="images/work-icon-9.jpg" alt="" /></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

This is the div that I need changed depending on which icon they click:

```
<div class="work-header"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want the background-image to change to?

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
  $('#word-header').css('background-image', 'url("img.jpg")');
});
```

Is the basic syntax. Elaborate a little more and I'll update this.

**edit** You can store the background-image as an HTML5 'data-' attribute on each icon, like so:

```
<img src="images/work-icon-1.jpg" alt="" data-header-img="images/header-1.jpg" />
```

And then do the jQuery like this:

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
  $('#word-header').css('background-image', "url("+$(this).attr('data-header-img')+")");
});
```

Fading the images is more complex. You can find a lot of solutions on Google, or hopefully someone will take the time here to show you how.

Answer (score 1):

Fading in backgrounds can indeed be much more complex, but it seems that in your situation you can use a little different approach by simply fading in an absolute positioned div behind the elements in question.  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DonamiteIsTNT/TwPpK/) demonstrates this.  Essentially, the necessary jquery is:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#img1").fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});
```

But of course you'd want to expand that to better handle a list of buttons and fade out previously clicked "backgrounds". You could store the id of the div to fade in a `data-bgElementId` attribute (or whatever) of the `<a>` tag, then use that in the click handler:

```
$(".thumb").click(function() {
    var bgElementId = $(this).attr("data-bgElementId"),
        bgElement = $("#" + bgElementId);

    bgElement.fadeIn(1000);
    $(".allBGs").not(bgElement).fadeOut(1000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies.  Could I send you both the actual link to the page itself to show you exactly what I'm talking about?

Comment: You should include the link in your question text. I am sure others will find your question helpful at some point and someone may know of a better solution. If you don't want to link to your server, consider making a jsfiddle